# Grails Web page with split site structure

Tags: grails

I need to "split" my website to three parts and have its structure lite his
`homepage.com/
homepage.com/second/
homepage.com/third/`

and in each should have ../login/ and ../user/create/ and all that

Do I need to add additional views and controller for the other ones or it is my server that should do the work (its a tomecat-server, but I have not much experience with it)
or is it something else I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're talking about Multi Tenancy - there are a lot of options but here's a start:

- http://gorm.grails.org/latest/hibernate/manual/index.html#multiTenancy
- http://guides.grails.org/discriminator-per-tenant/guide/index.html
- http://guides.grails.org/database-per-tenant/guide/index.html

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to add additional views and controller for the other ones or
>   it is my server that should do the work (its a tomecat-server, but I
>   have not much experience with it) or is it something else I need to
>   do?

It really depends on what the application needs to do.  Conceivably you could have all of this serviced by a single view and a single controller:

```
homepage.com/
homepage.com/second/
homepage.com/third/
```

Don't think of a 1-to-1-to-1 mapping between URLS to controllers to views.  You can have 1 controller and many views.  You can have 1 view and many controllers.  You can map multiple URLs to the same controller.  The framework offers you a lot of flexibility around all of that.  To optimize that, you have to understand what the application needs to do, which isn't expressed here.

The bottom line is you have options.